# Pass PHP Variable into WHERE/AND MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pass a value for a query that takes in a variable from an earlier Sql query and then compares the result against a field from another table. But I can't seem to figure out my syntax.

```
$topName = $row_rsAdminDetails['fullName'] ;

  $TESTqueryTwo = 
      "SELECT * FROM participants, admin WHERE admin.over_id = participants.fk_over_id AND participants.dr_over_names LIKE '%$topName%'";

  $TESTresult2 = mysql_query($TESTqueryTwo) or die(mysql_error());
```

the php output I'm looking to do:

```
  <?php
  // Print out the contents of each row  
  while($row_TESTresultTwo = mysql_fetch_array($TESTresultTwo)){
      echo $row_TESTresultTwo['userName']. " - ".   $row_TESTresultTwo['Participant_Name'];
      echo "<br />"; 
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Once try with this $TESTqueryTwo ="SELECT * FROM participants, admin WHERE admin.over_id = participants.fk_over_id AND participants.dr_over_names LIKE '%".$topName."%'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem could be on this line:

```
while($row_TESTresultTwo = mysql_fetch_array($TESTresultTwo)){
```

should be

```
while($row_TESTresultTwo = mysql_fetch_array($TESTresult2)){
     // as you have no $TESTresultTwo variable...
}
```

And also try with the query ... with `LIKE '%".$topName."%'"`

Comment: Thank you @Riad that was EXACTLY it. So silly, I can't believe I missed that. I know better than to mix numbers into variable names all willy nilly like that!